# Javascript. Uncaught ReferenceError: SPACE is not defined

Tags: javascript

I'm getting this error on my KeyUpHandler and my KeyDownHandler but I'm pretty sure I have it defined. if I could get some help with this that would be greatly appreciated. I don't know if it's human error or if my code is just messing up. I have tried fixing the error by changing my code around a bit but I am still getting this error when I press the space bar. I'm still new to JavaScript and I am struggling a bit with this error as I have tried looking it up on the internet but I haven't had any luck.

```
//Game states
var LOADING = 0
var PLAYING = 1;
var OVER = 2;
var gameState = LOADING;

//Arrow key codes
var UP = 38;
var DOWN = 40;

//Directions
var moveRight = false;
var moveLeft = false;
var moveUp = false;
var moveDown = false;

//Variables to help fire missiles
var shoot = false;
var spaceKeyIsDown = false;

//game variables
var alienFrequency = 100;
var alienTimer = 0;

//Add keyboard listeners

window.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
window.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);

function keyDownHandler (event)
{
  switch(event.keyCode)
  {
        
      case UP:
        moveUp = true;
        break;  
        
      case DOWN:
        moveDown = true;
        break;
        
        case SPACE:
        if(!spaceKeyIsDown)
        {
          shoot = true;
          spaceKeyIsDown = true;
        }
  }
}

function keyUpHandler (event)
{
  switch(event.keyCode)
  {     
        
      case UP:
        moveUp = false;
        break;  
        
      case DOWN:
        moveDown = false;
        break;
        
         case SPACE:
        spaceKeyIsDown = false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

... where do you define space?

you must define it before you can use it.

```
const space = 32;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing SPACE variable. You have to define it as:

```
var SPACE = 32;
```